# Why does this if-statement based on short-circuited evaluation not work?

Tags: javascript

In the `fun` function, I want to return 1 if the boolean expression is true.

```
function fun() {
    (1 == 1) && return 1;
}

alert(fun());
```

​Of course, I can easily do this with `if (1 == 1) return 1`. However, I am wondering why the above code does not work. It triggers a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return" error in the console in Chrome.

Shouldn't `return 1` only run if `(1 == 1)` is true? Why does this not work?

Comment: You, Sir, are probably coming from the Ruby world, where everything has got a return value, aren't you? :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `&&` operator needs `expressions` for both of its operands.  E.g.,

> expr1 && expr2

`return` statements, however, are not (grammatically speaking) `expressions`.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: Ah ok, so the `&&` operator needs two expressions. An expression, by definition, must evaluate to a value. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. As stated on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators), "An expression is any valid unit of code that resolves to a value."

Answer (score 2):

For an awesome explanation see jmar777's answer, and here is how you could realize your plan anyway. I just turned it the other way around:

```
function fun() {
    return null || 1 == 1;
}

alert(fun());
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess one might as well return `1 == 1` in that case though.

Comment: In this case of course it's the same. But if you are using another expression or the return value of a function call instead of `1 == 1`, then it's not: In the case that the expression on the right is not false, then the return value of the whole expression would be the value of the right, not simply `true`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript isn't bash shell scripting.  You have no `if`.  JavaScript also isn't C.  `==` automatically casts, but `===` doesn't, making `===` a wiser choice in almost every circumstance.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by "You have no `if`"?

Comment: this works: `if (1 === 1) return 1;` but this doesn't: `(1 == 1) && return 1;`  The former is JavaScript, the latter is /bin/sh